# Navigation dots on PowerPoint

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

Is there any way to make MS PowerPoint (Office 365) slides with navigation dots in the header, like the ones that you can make with LaTeX Beamer?

[Example 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wdU9a.png)

[Example 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MYwJs.png)

Comment: Try googling "powerpoint breadcrumbs" (w/o the quote marks).

Answer (score 0):

This is done using ordinary PowerPoint shapes:

1. Select any shape, in your example circles.
2. Create as many as required, formatted as preferred. You may also use themes.
3. Hyperlink each shape to the relevant slide by clicking on it, pressing
   <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>
   and selecting the slide to link.
   Or right-click each shape, select *Hyperlink > Place in this document*
   and select the slide.
4. Once complete, paste all the shapes to top of each PowerPoint slide,
   changing the format of the shape corresponding to the current slide.

That's all.

Comment: I know how to hyperlink a shape to a slide. My question is about creating those circles automatically based on section name and number of slides. If it's possible that those circles have hyperlinks that's even better, but I don't really need hyperlinks.

Comment: No automatic mechanism exists for that. You will need to write a VBA macro. For beginning you could have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35204216/165358).